# Есть ли специальный Adapter для красивого вывода информации по датам?

Tags: android, adapter

У меня есть БД с датами года и некой инфой на эти даты, нужно красиво вывести их по порядку, чтобы сначала была строка с названием месяца, а потом шли строки с днями в этом месяце, потом следующий месяц, потом опять даты и т.п., пример на изо. [image]

Comment: Честно говоря, мне кажется, что в этом случае лучше было бы использовать ExpandableListView и соответственно ExpandableListAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно в таких случаях создается новый класс на базе стандартного **Array Adapter**( наследуется ). Стандартный же поддерживает только работу с простыми типами данных.

Сигнатура нового класса адаптера будет иметь примерно такой вид:

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItemType>{ ... }
```

Далее, переопределяя родительский метод `getView(...)` вы предоставляете собственное отображение каждого элемента адаптера, созданное с помощью инфлейтинга( Inflating ) своей разметки в LinearLayout.

Comment: НУ,вообще,я думал,что можно расширить CursorAdapter,т.к. данные будут браться из БД

Comment: Если вы загляните в иерархию наследования( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html ), то заметите, что и ArrayAdapter, и CursorAdapter наследуются от одного и того же класса - BaseAdapter. Следовательно, все вышесказанное справедливо и для CursorAdapter.

Comment: спасибо,убедили

Comment: @BORSHEVIK берите `SimpleCursorAdapter` там много уже много чего реализовано - допишете свое и вперед

Comment: @Barmaley, SimpleCursorAdapter устарел, не?

Comment: @SuperCreeper,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Устарел один из конструкторов класса, а не весь класс..